# Intl.DateTime formatter get invalid time every time even after rerendering component. React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, localization, intl

We have a component that receives information from the backend and has to render it, its properties are as follows:

```
interface CitizenshipProps {
    citizenship?: Citizenship;
    name?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    onUpdateClick?: () => void;
}
```

Now, the `Citizenship` type is:

```
export interface Citizenship {
    nationalId: string;
    dateOfBirth: string;
    city: string;
    district: string;
    streetName: string;
    unitNumber: number;
    postCode: number;
    updatedAt: string;
}
```

We want `updatedAt` to be `Date` type (instead of `string` shown above).
We intended to render it as follows:

```
<S.ProfileContentRowData
    type="body"
    size="medium"
    variant="regular"
>
    {dateTimeFormatter.format(citizenship?.updatedAt)}
</S.ProfileContentRowData>
```

Where

```
const dateTimeFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat(userLang, {
    dateStyle: 'full',
    timeStyle: 'medium',
});
```

It should has sense since `Inte.DateTimeFormat.format` accepts either `number`, `Date` or `undefined`:

```
interface DateTimeFormat {
        format(date?: Date | number): string;
        resolvedOptions(): ResolvedDateTimeFormatOptions;
    }
```

However, it is not the case and the component always throws `RangeError: Invalid time value`.

We can say it is understandable at the first rendering since the `Citizenship` property is undefined (and the formatter receives `undefined`, it should not be a problem); but, when the card receives the data, it even shows the same error(and we checked it by using effect, trying to check it both with and without formatter, and the date comes as `Date`).

We really don't understand this behavior.

Right now, we solved it by getting the `updatedAt` as a `string` instead, and enforcing the rendering by checking if `Citizenship` is not `undefined`:

```
{citizenship?.updatedAt !== undefined && (
    <S.ProfileContentRowData
        type="body"
        size="medium"
        variant="regular"
    >
        {dateTimeFormatter.format(
            new Date(citizenship?.updatedAt || '')
        )}
    </S.ProfileContentRowData>
)}
```

We would like to understand why are we getting that error, and whether fetching **DateTime** values from the backend as `Date` in the front-end is a good practice or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> whether fetching **DateTime** values from the backend as `Date` in the front-end is a good practice or not

It depends on the channel you use between back and front, and the data serialization that channel performs.

In most cases, one uses a standard HTTP request/response with JSON data format.

In that case, `Date` format is not supported as a type, but converted to string instead (e.g. `"2022-09-08T12:34:56Z"`).

So you will need a conversion first (typically `new Date(dateStr)` as you have done in your workaround) before formatting.

Comment: Well, it was done by `axios` itself, we just declared that variable as `Date` in the interface declaration, so it comes a `Date`, that's why this behavior is very strange for us.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean: by default, axios does _not_ transform a string representing a serialized date into a JS `Date` object. Can you share what makes you think so? You can however customize axios to have some automatic transform, e.g. with [`axios-date-reviver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-date-reviver)

Comment: well, when I do check the parsed data, it is already converted to a date, and it seems a valid one.

Comment: Sorry without further details on this specific behaviour, I can only blind guess, which is unproductive for everyone...

Comment: You could log the data and share the content for example